# How can I monitor/control applications making network connections?

Tags: networking, security

I found out about `nethogs` and `iftop` the other day, and ran them. I was surprised to see some applications running daemons I didn't know about. It's fine now that I know about them, but I'd like to be more aware of this sort of thing in future, mainly to save bandwidth!

Is there a single Ubuntu application that:

1. monitors which applications are making connections
2. monitors where they're connecting to
3. would request my permission before making a connection
4. (less important) monitors how much they've uploaded/downloaded

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netstat` for your 1. and 2. points. Although `netstat` is not a background running process. But once run it, you can see which applications are waiting for incoming connections, which applications are connected to which peer, etc.